# Set default text / values for fontsize and fontfamily in tinymce.init()

Tags: tinymce

I'm using Bootstrap 3, and intializing tinyMCE (5.1.0) within a local modal (it's inside the page which is calling it, not being loaded externally) like this:

```
        tinymce.init({ 
            mode: "specific_textareas", 
            plugins : 'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview textcolor',
            toolbar: "undo redo fontselect fontsizeselect bold italic underline forecolor backcolor alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify",
            editor_selector: "txtContent",
            height: 400
        });
```

and it works. However, the dropdowns for fontsize and font family dropdowns have no initial value, like shown on the following image.
[image: empty select]

Is there a way for me to set (or preselect) the default text (or value) of both dropdowns? If so, how should do it? I've Googled about, and have found nothing regarding this.

I've noticed that when I focus out, the selects are filled with System font, and 12pt, respectively, so I guess I could focus in and out of them in order to achieve what I want, but there has to be a better way of doing it.

**EDIT** I've also used this:

```
        tinymce.init({ 
            mode: "specific_textareas", 
            plugins : 'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview textcolor',
            toolbar: "undo redo fontselect fontsizeselect bold italic underline forecolor backcolor alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify",
            editor_selector: "txtContent",
            height: 400,
            setup: function(ed) {
                ed.on('init',function(){
                    ed.execCommand("fontName",false,"Arial");
                    ed.execCommand("fontSize",false,"12");
                });
            }
        });
```

While this actually works, something resets the dropdowns back to their original (empty) values, and if I press CTRL + Z, I can see the code had worked (the values were actually selected).

**EDIT**: The issue is within Bootstrap and the way it handles modals.

Comment: FYI `mode: "specific_textareas"` was depreciated prior to v 5.x. All you need to declare is  `editor_selector` (Not related to your current issue though...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `content_styles:` to apply a default font to the body of the embedded iframe. This font information is then reflected in the dropdowns on page load. Here is a Tiny Fiddle demonstration:
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/nTgaab

You can also use `content_css` in a similar fashion by linking to a remote CSS file with similar font information.

Here's some more information:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_style
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_css

Comment: This seems to have helped somewhat, and after fiddling about with the editor, and continuous link hopping from the ones you provided, it seems that my problem was in another direction altogether - the editor was in a modal, and Bootstrap was stopping the propagation. So my issue seems to have been different from what I'd originally thought. Still, thank you for pointing me in what turned out to be a good direction.